# Accidentally shutdown system while Bitcoin Core client was synchronizing

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

My computer was accidentally shutdown while Bitcoin Core was synchronizing and it is now giving the error `fatal error please see error log`. Please tell me what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: What does the debug.log say?

Comment: You must back up the wallet before doing anything. Don't lose the private keys. If you have your private keys you can re-install everything back anytime.

Answer (score 1):

> **giving an error as ' fatal error please see error log' ... what is the solution to this problem.**

Step one is to do as it suggests. The location of the error log depends on the platform (Windows probably `%APPDATA%\bitcoin`, Linux probably `~/.bitcoin`)

If all else fails, just install some wallet software elsewhere and re-import the private key you carefully backed up for just this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the blockchain data is corrupt, in that case you should delete the blockchain files on your computer and let it sync again. Might take a while though, as Bitcoin's database is quite large.